# Java: Replace lists - bug

Tags: java, list

I have two identical lists. I want to replace one of them to the latter, but it does not work neither do I get any errors.

This is my code: (Lists is the class)

```
Lists.ident = Lists.ident2;
```

Why doesn't this work in some cases?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Here you are referring ident2 with ident referrence. This is not replacing the list

Answer (score 1):

That is not the proper way of replacing lists.

Try this:

```
Lists.ident = new LinkedList<String>(Lists.ident2);
```

Please read the various methods available for lists for further questions.